# Constraints collision between size classes

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, size-classes

I want to create constraints which simply create a vertical space between two views.

First I create it in the wAny hAny size class with a space of 40.

Then I want to have the same constraint with other values in other size classes.

But when I create the same constraint, just with another value Xcode gives me an

```
auto-layout error that those constraints are colliding.
```

Because wAny hAny is valid in all other size-classes as well.

In a first attempt I have deleted the constraint out of the wAny hAny size class but then I get the

```
auto-layout error that the layout is not defined correctly in wAny hAny.
```

So, it does not matter how I create it, there is always an auto-layout error. I think I just missed a basic concept here to understand what is going wrong. Can somebody explain it to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Any Any constraint will automatically be applied to every resolution if you want different constraint for a specific resolution then change the size class and then change its constraints value for that specific device. it will only be applied to that specific device.Any Any will not be changed. I just tried it now

Comment: What I mean - I want to change only the value of the _same_ constraint. Creating another constraint with the same meaning collides with the existing wAny hAny constraint. But just changing the value of the existing constraint changes it also for wAny hAny.

Comment: If you want to create another constraint, change the priority of original constraint to 999. They won't collide.

Comment: Changing the value of constraint on another class will not affect the original wAny hAny constraint value. I tried it here.

Comment: Thanks for you help Muhammad, but I am experiencing exactly the opposite here. I have tried it now multiple times. I have created also a blank new project so that the result is not affected by any side effects. Step 1: create an image view, set constraints in Any Any. Step 2: create another image view, set constraints and create one constraint which defines the vertical gap to image 1 in Any Any. Step 3: change to another size class and change the vertical gap on the _same_ constraint. Step 4: change back to Any Any and see that the gap is now also updated in Any Any.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. I was doing it wrong. What I have done is - changing the size-class by selecting the size-class in IB (clicking on wAny hAny at the bottom of the IB screen) and then just set another constant value. This does not work.

This is how it works. Go to the size inspector and click on the plus sign on the left of the constant. Now add the size class. This creates a *second* constant for the new size class.

[image]

Now setting the value on the *second* constant does work. The original hAny wAny size class is not affected.